# Regarding an instance of simulating the functionality of 2D arrays in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

```
arr = [
"xxyyyxxxx",
"xxxeeexxx",
"xwwwxxxxx",
]
```

I've seen code similar to this used to simulate 2 dimensional arrays in python by parsing the contents using for in row and for in col. Using this method what would be the easiest way to identify a specific "index" (or rather the location of a character within a certain string). If you don't have to modify the array and having to type out the entire array isn't an issue would there still be a better way to simulate a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: Can you provide more specifications about your questions ? Please be more descriptive about the issue with a test-case if possible

Comment: What is your question again? The one above seems confusing. One sentence, perhaps?

Comment: Two answers and yet the question isn't even clear. Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable sequences that can be indexed just like lists. So here,

```
arr[0][2]
```

Would take the string with index 0, and from that the character with index 2 -- "y". So that works.

Better ways to do it depends on what you need to do exactly. Real 2D arrays are available in Numpy.

Answer (score 0):

to get the position of a specific character you could do a 2D loop like so

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr[i])):
        if arr[i][j]=="e":
            print str(i), ", ", str(j)
```